# How to constrain the height of LazyVGrid?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to set the height of LazyVGrid to 0.8 of the screen size.

MRE:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct QuestionApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Grid()
        }
    }
}

struct Grid: View {
    var columns: [GridItem]
    
    init() {
        columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0), count: 4)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1..<33) { num in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                        .overlay {
                            Text(String(num))
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.8)
        }
    }
}

struct Grid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Grid()
    }
}
```

What I get on the iPad Mini: https://i.imgur.com/LDs5vWH.png

What I want: https://i.imgur.com/Yz5Ku6N.png

I basically want to constrain the LazyVGrid height to no more than 0.8 of GeometryReader's height and **make its width shrink accordingly**. But with lots of trial and error and playing with .frame (width, height, maxWidth, and maxHeight) I couldn't make it shrink as I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing and experimenting with the ideas I got from @carbonr I've come to the conclusion that in order to constrict the Height of LazyVStack, you must manipulate its Width only.

The working code is:

```
struct Grid: View {
    var columns: [GridItem]
    var nums = 36
    
    init() {
        columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0), count: 4)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            let cellSize = geo.size.height * (1 / CGFloat(nums / columns.count))
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<nums) { num in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                        .overlay {
                            Text(String(num))
                        }
                }
            }
            //HERE:
            .frame(maxWidth: cellSize * CGFloat(columns.count) * 0.8)
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has corrections — I'm happy to hear them. Otherwise, I'll mark this answer as accepted.